# creating hydrogenated castor oil/sebacic acid copolymer

Tags: polymers

I would like to create a copolymer using Hydrogenated castor oil and Sebacic acid to create a hair conditioning treatment, however I dont know where to begin so any advice will be highly appreciated.

I would like to know how a copolymer is formed, is it as simple as mixing sebacic acid and Hydrogenated Castor Oil under heat?

What formula should I use to work out the proportions of Hydrogenated Castor Oil and Sebacic Acid?

What formula should be used to work out the temperature needed to begin the chemical reaction?

How do I ensure that the chemical reaction has finished? Is there any formulas to work out the time needed for the chemical reaction of let's say 10g of sebacic acid and 50g of hydrogenated castor oil?

Is there any other substances that must be used to start the polymerisation or is sebacic acid and hydrogenated castor oil enough?

Any advise would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: You might start with the application of your finished product, and why you would choose *hydrogenated* oil.  Unsaturated "drying oils" like linseed polymerize into coatings by reacting with O2.  You might be able to make *polyester* with sebacic and castor, but for what?

Comment: The application for the finished product is for a hair conditioning treatment. I would like to test the efficacy.

Comment: Well, my advice is to not do it yourself. Sorry, but it appears you don't know first thing about making polyesters :( If you have some chemist friend you could try to do it together.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, could you point me in the direction to learn the first thing about making copolymers?

Comment: Making esters can be done under nitrogen with a mixer and heat.  Water is the by product of esterification and should begin to distill off when the temperature reaches above 350F.  Xylene can be used to help the water off.  Water will split out from xylene when it condenses.  Since the alcohol group on castor oil is inhibited, the rxn may be slow.  The finished product may have a higher viscosity, which may help for hair products!

Comment: Thank you for the information Robert. I will have to learn quite a bit more! It seems more complicated than I initially thought 